# google cloud shell keyboard shortcuts clashing with browser

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I'm using google's cloud shell tool to develop remotely, and it has quite a nice VS-Code like env. However the keyboard shortcuts clash with the browser. Is there any way to override / prevent this?

FWIW I'm using this on a pixelbook where you can pop out any web site as an "app" (like a PWA) so it's not a browser window per se, but the shortcuts still clash. For example ctrl-W will close the whole window.

I've seen google sheets and other web apps trap the browser commands so wondering if there's some setting in cloud shell i haven't found yet.

Comment: I recommend to you use SSH connection, shell is not safe for a production environment. You can make an GCE F1-micro is free tier https://cloud.google.com/free

Answer (score 0):

> FWIW I'm using this on a pixelbook where you can pop out any web site as an "app" (like a PWA) so it's not a browser window per se, but the shortcuts still clash. For example ctrl-W will close the whole window.

Are you using the PWA or just the open as shortcut mode?  Try the PWA if you are using the open in own window approach.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the nearest to "app" mode there is, I clicked the [+] button in the browser bar and now have a standalone app "shell" icon on my apps bar and no browser chrome when launching it.